# How to Disable Touchpad gestures in windows?

Tags: windows-10, search, touchpad

Windows latest update has introduced some two finger gestures, how to disable ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way, we have to go to control-panel -> Hardware & sound -> mouse -> find settings at the right middle -> select multi-finger -> three-finger -> uncheck "enable tapping" and if you wish you can remove checkbox "Enable Gestures" , this actually solved my search popup in windows laptop.
See following image, showing highlights.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2kEL.png)